# What is a PHP function to return multiple rows from a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to php, and to this point I've been fine using the mysql_fetch_array function to echo values selected from the database. But now I want to be able to echo the results selected from multiple rows with the same username.

I was just wondering what the most efficient way of doing this was. I could manage to do it using a for loop and counting through each individual query, but I know there must be a more efficient way just using sql, or using a better oho function.

Thank you for the help.

Alex

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    // process each row
}
```

I guess that's all you neeed  - have a play and you should get your desired effect! It's best to do it in PHP..

Also you shouldn't use `mysql_fetch_array` anymore as it's deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli insted. More information you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is used to query the database your using. PHP is used to format the output from the query. See the manual from PHP.net for more info [php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) . There is no way as far as I know to format the output in rows using SQL.

B.T.W. if this is new code I would advice you to use mysqli instead of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
} or
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
}
```

and mysql_ functions are depreciated now onwards in mysql